# aws s3 notification include metadata information

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that gets notification whenever and s3 object gets added.  The function then reads some metadata of the s3 object.  Is there any way to include the metadata in the notification itself, rather than me having to go and read the head object.

Answer (score 5):

The [event notification data structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) does not include object metadata or tags, and there is not a way to enable their inclusion.

Answer (score -1):

No, S3 event notification does not include metadata or tags. You have to explicitly get it through **head-object**

aws s3api head-object --bucket my_bucket --key my-file.json

Comment: Please provide link(s) to documentation.